# Mechanical Disk Brake Pads Too Thick

Tags: brakes, repair, disc-brake, replacement, brake-pads

I decided to replace my front brake pads since they are worn out beyond function. So after removing the old pads, I made sure the piston was fully out, and the adjusting screw was fully tight as well, and still I could not get both of the pads in. I can get only one of them in perfectly so I do not doubt a compatibility issue.

I decided to take out some of my worn-out brake pads from the rear brake so at least I would have *some* braking power in the front but I could not remove the rear brakes because they were also too thick to get out. What other options do I have other than manually opening the caliper in half?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  As always, some pictures might help; something a potential answerer can't quite imagine might be quite obvious to them when looking at a photo.

Comment: There are some calipers where you have to sequence the inner and outer correctly or you won't have the clearance you need - let us know what brake you have.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, will attach a picture once available, in the meantime I'm afraid I am using an off-brand caliper that came with the bike. My bike is a turkish "Volta VB1" ebike, if that helps though.

Comment: Related - possible dupe: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32745/disk-brake-pads-too-thick

Answer (score 1):

I've asked around other people who use the same brakes, turns out I have to de-assemble the caliper and then install the new pads. Incredibly bad design but apparently it is what it is.

Comment: which caliper is this? as it stands, neither the question or answer is very information to future readers who might have a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a pad compatibility issue: I believe after market pads are the same width.

But the next step would be to try it without the cable attached at all.  Also I would clean the pistons.  They may be stuck.